# linux/unix convert delimited file to fixed width

Tags: linux, unix, sh

I have a requirement to convert a delimited file to fixed-width file, details as follows.

**Input file sample:**

```
AAA|BBB|C|1234|56
AA1|BB2|DD|12345|890
```

**Output file sample:**

```
AAA  BBB   C   1234  56  
AA1  BB2   DD  12345 890
```

**Details of field positions**

- Field 1 Start at position 1 and length should be 5
- Field 2 start at position 6 and length should be 6
- Field 3 Start at position 12 and length should be 4
- Field 4 Start at position 16 and length should be 6
- Field 5 Start at position 22 and length should be 3

Answer (score 0):

With the following `awk` command you can achive your goal:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=" "; FS="|" } { printf "%5s%6s%4s%6s%3s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5 }' your_input_file
```

Your record separator (`RS`) is a space and your field separator (`FS`) is a pipe (`|`) character. In order to parse your data correctly we set them in the `BEGIN` statement (before any data is read). Then using `printf` and the desired format characters we output the data in the desired format.

***Output:***

```
  AAA   BBB   C  1234 56
  AA1   BB2  DD 12345890
```

***Update:***

I just saw your edits on the input file format (previously they seemed different). If your input data records are separated with a new line then simply remove the `RS=" ";` part from the above one-liner and apply the `-` modifiers for the format characters to left align your fields:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { printf "%-5s%-6s%-4s%-6s%-3s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5 }' your_input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution:

```
echo -e "AAA|BBB|C|1234|56\nAA1|BB2|DD|12345|890" | 
awk -F '|' '{printf "%-5s%-6s%-4s%-6s%-3s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'
```

Note the `-` before the `%-3s` in the printf statement, which will left-align the fields, as required in the question. Output:

```
AAA  BBB   C   1234  56 
AA1  BB2   DD  12345 890
```